# Masonite - Corrupted Content error on redirection to '/'

Tags: python, frameworks, masonite

I'm using the Masonite framework and whenever I have this code:

```
def another(self, Request):
    return Request.redirect('/')
```

Whenever that is hit and it is redirecting, it will either throw a Corrupted Content error or an Infinite Redirection error depending on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

### Fix

This was fixed in Masonite 1.6.5 so you can just run:

```
pip install --upgrade masonite
```

and that should fix the problem.

### The Problem

The problem was because of how Masonite compiled routes into a url. Some url's can be left untouched (such as redirecting to `/` or `/home`) but some need to be compiled down such as redirecting to `/dashboard/user/@user/@id` so Masonite has a special method for compiling routes.

Anyways, Masonite would also always prepend a `/` and there was a bug that would compile the route of `/` into `//` which typically makes the browser throw that error. That has since been tested and fixed.